# How can I save a SQL stored procedure file path into another folder using a c# console application

Tags: console, console-application

I need to get the data from the stored procedure which contains the local file path and save the path that contains .xslx files into another folder locally using a console application.

Comment: This is a fairly involved process. You will have a better chance to get an answer if you tell what you have tried, what worked and what didn't. Or if you need help to get started, then be clear that you need help on what tools or libraries to use.